# Target parent element by href attribute and add content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

this is my current html:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
</div>
```

I need to add a new div as a last element of this structure. This is what I want to achieve:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
</div>

<div>
    added element
</div>
```

I need to target it by href attribute. This is what I've tried but it's not working:

```
jQuery('a[href$="http://example.com"]').parent().append('<div>added element</div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but that will append the `div` *within* the `div` that has the anchor in it.

You want to add it *next to* that `div` using `after` rather than `append`:

```
jQuery('a[href$="http://example.com"]').parent().after('<div>added element</div>');
// ----------------------------------------------^
```

**Live Example:**

```js
jQuery('a[href$="http://example.com"]').parent().after('<div>added element</div>');
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```